# Converting Monstrous JavaScript code to elegant Clojurescript code

Tags: clojurescript

I have such terrible JavaScript code

```
response.items[0].fields.image.fields.file.url
```

I can convert it to ClojureScipt map, but to access that field I will have to type monstrous unreadable access.
Is there a way to do it nice and elegant way way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(-> (aget (.-items response) 0)
    (.. -fields -image -fields -file -url))
```

or if you have converted it to a Clojure data structure:

```
(-> response :items first :fields :image :fields :file :url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [cljs-oops](https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-oops#be-more-expressive-with-selectors) library. It support nested "selectors" for your object graph, e.g.:

```
(oget o "k3.?k31.k311")
(oget o "k3" "?k31" :k311)
(oget o ["k3" "?k31" "k311"])
(oget o [["k3"] "?k31"] "k311")
```

Comment: I will investigate but from first sight I did say for myself "wtf" :D

Comment: I also use `cljs-oops` and do recommend it, but also wanted to show the vanilla cljs solution.